# Getting the value from a return observable inside catchError

Tags: angular, rxjs

`budgetTestService.getBudgetDates` returns an observable, how can I get the `BudgetDate[]` value from it in catchError?

```js
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
  .pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      self.timelineBudgetDates = self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate);
        return of('some return value');
      }
    )
  )
  .subscribe(res => {
    self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);          
  });
```

**Error:**

```
Type 'Observable<BudgetDate[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'BudgetDate[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

Comment: What does `budgetService.getBudgetDays` return? What do you want to do with the `BudgetDate[]` in `catchError`?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of Higher order function to pass this reference to catch

```
const errorHandler=(self)=>error => {
              self.timelineBudgetDates = 
              self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate);
              return of('some return value');
            }
          )

this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
        .pipe(
          catchError(errorHandle(this))
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
          self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the budgetService from a component, you should be able to map the response without the need to subscribe.  catchError is only execututed when the service throws an error.  Please see code below...

```
    this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
        .pipe(
          map(res => { self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res); }), 
          catchError(error => {
              // handle error
            })
         );
```

Comment: i thought observables need subscriptions to invoke the http call

Comment: and i have to use budgetTestService.getBudgetDates() in catchError, it returns an observable how can I map BudgetDate[]?

Comment: Http Calls return a promise that can mapped into an observable by RxJs, which is then returned by the service (ie: budgetService).  To use it in a component,  you can call the service and use the .pipe operator to transform the observable returned from the service to use in your component.  In my opinion, it is best practice to not allow side effects in your service and make your transformations in your component.

Comment: To handle,your errors from the Http call,you would have the service throw an error if there is an error, and the component can use catchError and perform logic there.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using switchMap:

```js
this.budgetService.getBudgetDays(this.startDate, this.finishDate)
  .pipe(
    catchError(error => {
      return self.self.budgetTestService.getBudgetDates(self.startDate, self.finishDate)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(value => {
        return of(value);
        })
      }
    )
  .subscribe(res => {
    self.timelineBudgetDates = self.processDates(res);          
  });
```